# Using segues and nsnotificationcenter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsnotificationcenter

I have 2 viewcontrollers and I want to send a notification out from one to the other and have a label changed based on the name of the notification (pressing a UIButton). I just started using segues and found they are a very useful way to get from one view to another. The problem I am facing is that using a segue (modal at the moment), the second view controller is not receiving the notification. I believe that segues release and create new view controllers when used, not sure. Is there any way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at the `prepareForSegue:` method and you should be able to get rid of the notifications altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using NSNotification is not the right method for passing data from one VC to another. Like Rog said, use prepareForSegue and use a property on the destination VC:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Always check to make sure you are handling the right Segue
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) {
         MyOtherViewController *movc = segue.destinationViewController;
         movc.myProperty = @"MyValue";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hey I am trying to implement this, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I have: `if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GetRatingSegue"]){ Rating *rvc = segue.destinationViewController; rvc.trating.text = @"bad";}` where trating is a UILabel. When I click the button that runs the segue, the label in the new view isn't "bad".

Comment: Nevermind, got it working. Apparently can't use it on UI elements directly and had to use a NSString first. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, you'll need to set a property in the Rating VC.  Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepareForSegue` for going-to a segue, and use the delegate pattern for coming back. Within `prepareForSegue`, set the originating viewController as the delegate of the destination viewController. When returning, have the destination viewController call it's delegate (the original viewController) for whatever method you implement.